# Tree growing back after being removed

Tags: trees, pruning, tree-care

Our tree snapped into last spring and we had it removed and they ground it I believe with a machine.

I saw what I thought was a weed growing in it's place two month's ago which was about 2 to 3 inches tall and after looking closer the leaves looked like our tree. soooo....  I let it grow.

It is now 2 to 3 feet tall and looks more like a bush than a tree.  Will the stump eventually grow up or should I be doing something?

Comment: What species of tree was it? Please post a photo of the new growth if you have one. Thanks!

Comment: Need to know what tree it was - if it was grafted onto a different rootstock, that's what you'll have growing.

Answer (score 1):

It could well be your tree trying to grow again. Many trees can live that way, starting over and over.

Take a look at practice of coppicing: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppicing